# Threading infinity loops and sync problem

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, infinite

I am getting headache, trying to figure out how to deal with 2 threads in Python.

My Idea was to create one thread for blinking LEDs, that have infinite while loop, and when global variable changes to True,it starts to blink etc, but it is always in infinite loop.

other main thread, will be waiting for signal to blink, but also if the signal is while blinking, it will reset global blinking timer, so it has to be in separate thread.

Problem I am having, when I start LEDs thread from main thread, because LED thread has infinite loop, it stops main thread from running any further than `flashThread.start()`

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('starting main...')
    flashThread = threading.Thread(name='SFlashing', daemon = True, target=Flash)
    flashThread.start()
    while(True):
        print('running main...')
        time.sleep(2)
```

it never gets to  `running main...`

`Flash()` is just infinite while loop and depending on global variables it does stuff...

Comment: Indeed, [Python can only run one thread at a time](https://realpython.com/python-gil), so if your thread is busy looping, no other thread will have a chance to execute

Comment: is there any workaround ?

Comment: Use `multiprocessing` instead of `multithreading`

Comment: I think you can pause your blinking thread with `time.sleep`, like you're doing in the main thread

Comment: @ForceBru - Python will switch threads in the background, usually about once every .005 seconds. See `sys.getswitchinterval()` for your system.

Comment: @tdelaney, yeah, it should be switching, but it doesn't look like it's working in this case...

Comment: Your code should work. Can you post a working program demonstrating the problem? Sometimes people accidentally call the function when creating the thread (`Thread(name='SFlashing', daemon = True, target=Flash())`.

Comment: it works if i put some time sleeps in my Flash(). But I don't have any so it's just pure while(True)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a main thread printing `running main...` + a parallel thread incrementing a variable `count`, based on your explanations. Your code should work, maybe could you give us more information about the `Flash` loop so we can help you ?

```
import threading
import time

def Flash():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print("count", count)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)

print('starting main...')
flashThread = threading.Thread(name='SFlashing', daemon = True, target=Flash)
flashThread.start()
while(True):
    print('running main...')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output:

```
starting main...
count 0
running main...
count 1
running main...
count 2
count 3
running main...
```

** **EDIT** **
Here there is no more `time.sleep()`in Flash, until the global variable `toto`is changed in the main loop.

```
import threading
import time

global toto
toto = 0

def Flash():
    global toto
    count = 0
    while True:
        print("count", count)
        count += 1
        if toto == 2:
            print("YEEHA")
            time.sleep(2)

print('starting main...')
flashThread = threading.Thread(name='SFlashing', daemon = True, target=Flash)
flashThread.start()
while(True):
    print('running main...')
    time.sleep(1)
    toto = 2
```

Comment: that works because there is time.sleep(1)in my case Flash() doesn't have any time.sleep until some variables changes

Comment: Have a look at my EDIT part, I remove the time.sleep in Flash until a global variable `toto` is changed

Comment: I just tested it, and it behaves just like mine. so it only prints count. Is it maybe because I am using raspberry PI ?

Comment: On my screen, it prints count 10232 times, and then it prints "YEEHA", "running main...", "count" again and so on. I don't know if the problem comes from raspberry pi :/